# Diffie-Hellman key exchange for three user.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Assume that there are three users that have their own secret key $d_i$ and corresponding public key $Q_i = d_i G$ such that $Q_i$ is a point in an elliptic curve. Now I'm looking for a solution to produce a value that any one of this three users can produce with their own secret key $d_i$ and the public keys of the other two users? ($G$ is a basepoint in the elliptic curve and $Q_i$'s are points in the elliptic curve)
**Note**, like Diffie-Hellman where two users with secret keys $d_1$ and $d_2$ and public keys $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, respectively, can produce the value $Z$ such that $Z= d_1 d_2 G = d_1 Q_2 = d_2 Q_1$.

Comment: There is a cryptosystem called **Massey-Omura** for n-user. But, I don't sure if it has same complexity of DH. @star